# Proguard - Keep line numbers for J2ME/BlackBerry applications

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, ant, java-me, proguard

I've search all over the web and this problem is driving me crazy.
I'm building a mobile application (J2ME, BB) using ANT and Proguard.

In my **javac task**, I've added the debuglevel paramater, like so:

```
<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${tmp.dir}${application.name}" failonerror="true" source="1.4" target="1.4" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source">
```

In my **proguard task**, I have:

```
<proguard defaultpackage="" usemixedcaseclassnames="false" note="false" microedition="true" verbose="true" printmapping="true" optimizationpasses="10" renamesourcefileattribute="SourceFile">
...
...
<keepattribute name="LineNumberTable" />
<keepattribute name="SourceFile" /> 
</proguard>
```

However, when I look at the output console in Eclipse (after building my application and launching it on an emulator), I don't see lines number, just stuff like that:

```
at com.mycomp.myapp.Main.a(+47)
at gd.a(+24)
at fq.a(+368)
at fq.b(+188)
at com.mycomp.myapp.Main.run(+29)
```

I'm using Proguard 4.8.

Thanks a lot for your help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the correct setting in Proguard:

```
<keepattribute name="LineNumberTable" />
```

Do you see the line numbers on the console?, that worked for me.